# Suggested way to allow others to plugin to my php script and change variable values?

Tags: php

People want to use my Jquery plugin, but get a list of images from a database instead of a directory, which is the standard way the plugin works.

My Jquery plugin that uses the ajax() function to deliver & return data to a php script.

The php script pulls files from a directory with getdir(), adds those files to an array and assigns that array to a variable.

People have requested the ability to create that variable value themselves by generating it from a database (not just pulling files from a directory using scandir).

What is a good, secure way to do to allow others to replace a variable value inside my php script?

Ideally, I would like there to be a way where users can create their own script in a separate document (and they don't need to alter my document).

Here is a simplified example of my script:

HTML Document

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "example.php",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        foo: "some_directory",
            },
    success: function(html){
    alert(html);
    }
});
</script>
```

PHP Document

```
<?php

$foo = $_POST["foo"];
$foo = scandir($foo);
$foo = (explode(",",$foo)); // how can I allow others to change this variable value?
foreach ($foo as $a) {
    echo "<p>$a</p>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want to look into writing an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Api).

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm afraid of :) I'm a PHP novice and there are many different ways to write an API. Do you have any tips to get me started?

Comment: Upvoted, this was my first thought. I'd offer an answer, but I have no idea how to implement an API.

Comment: I'm about to start writing an API for an application that I'm working on.  To be honest, if I were you, I'd post another question on this site.  I may be able to give you some advice, but I'm by no means an expert at writing APIs and you'd probably find one if you ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Use event based programming. When it comes time to assign the variable, Detect whether a function called "onGetDirAssignVar" exists. If it does, call the function and accept it's results. If it doesn't, then follow the default path.

```
var $foo;
if (function_exists("onGetDirAssignVar")) {
  $foo = onGetDirAssignVar(params);
} else {
  $foo = array("first","second"); // how can I allow this value to be changed?
}

foreach ($foo as $a) {
    echo "<p>$a</p>";
}
```

Comment: My php script runs when a user submits data via AJAX. The data submitted is stored in an object literal. Are you suggesting that I:  1. Add a new member to the object literal where the user can enter a value php file name/location. 2. Assign that value to a PHP variable "onGetDirAssignVar". 3. Write logic that says "if onGetDirAssignVar != null, then include the PHP document represented by "onGetDirAssignVar"? And this would be included below & overwrite my existing variable declarations?

Comment: I'm really confused now, the data submitted by who is stored in an object literal where? Maybe give more details on what your script does and it might be possible to give a better answer as to what might more sense from your _users_ perspective. I was under the impression that these were developers making the request.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I updated my original question with more details. Please let me know if it's more clear.